# Getting author of a post django python

Tags: django, post, author

I'm trying to get the author of each post, so I've written this function in the views.py folder that allows you to add a post, except when I introduce post_form = poster I get errors

NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.author_id

Here is the addPost function:

```
def addPost(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    postAdded = False

    poster = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(data=request.POST)

        if post_form.is_valid():
            postAdded = True
            post_form.author = poster
            post_form.save()

        else:
            print(post_form.errors)

    else:
        post_form = PostForm()



    return render_to_response(
        'Forum/addPost.html',
        {'post_form': post_form, 'postAdded': postAdded},
        context)
```

and here are the relevant models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Post(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='poster')




class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        newPost = Post

        # newPost.category = check which url we are in

        model = newPost
        fields = ('title', 'body', 'category')
```

Thanks to all

Here is the error:

NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.author_id

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/nicolasanastassacos/Desktop/DjangoProject/blog/views.py" in addPost
  80.             post_form.save()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  457.                              construct=False)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_instance
  103.         instance.save()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  590.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  618.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  699.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  732.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  921.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  920.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  549.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  485.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /Forum/addPost/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.author_id
```

Comment: Please, show how `PostForm` looks like

Comment: edited to include PostForm. Thanks

Comment: Can you add the line that is causing the error or the traceback?

Comment: Added the exception reason and traceback.

Comment: Your blog_post table has an author_id column? Did you run migrations?

Comment: Sorry guys, I had provided the wrong error before. It was supposed to be NOT NULL constraint that wasn't satisfied, not no column. Thanks

Comment: @danielfranca Yes, I gave the wrong error as I tried a few other things. I have fixed the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is at your author instance. You are trying to create a form, setting it the values, adding it an author and saving it.
First, the form does not have an author field, you are excluding it with the line:

```
fields = ('title', 'body', 'category')
```

Try something like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

```
if post_form.is_valid():
            postAdded = True
            instance = post_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = poster
            instance.save()
```

That way you are not setting a NULL value to your author field.

Comment: The form doesn't have an author field because it was not supposed to be available for the users, but just the admin, and displayed using the html code.

This worked, thanks again.

Comment: I know why you would want to hide it. Just have in mind that a modelform is not an instance of your model, so you have to be careful on how you handle it. If this worked for you, accept it :p

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to something like that to avoid your error:

```
if post_form.is_valid():
    new_post = post_form.save(commit=False)
    new_post.author = poster
    new_post.save()
```